# Is it possible to use "javascript dot notation" in JINT with a Dictionary<string, object>

Tags: javascript, c#, jint

I have a set of JavaScript commands, such as `doc.page == 5`, and I'm using [JINT](http://jint.codeplex.com/) to execute the scripts within my C# application.

However, in my C# code, `doc` is a `Dictionary<string, object>`.  Therefore, I cannot use dot-notation in this way.

My current solution is terribly inefficient: I convert `doc` into a JSON string, and add that to my script.  The `Dictionary` is very large, so this has WAY more overhead than executing the simple command.  Here's some example code:

```
// Some example data:
var command = "doc.page < 5 || doc.tax < 10 || doc.efile";
var doc = new Dictionary<string, object>(){
    {"page", 5},
    {"tax", 10},
    {"efile", true},
    // ... etc ...
};

// Execute the command:

// Convert Dictionary to JSON:
var jsonDoc = new StringBuilder();
jsonDoc.Append("var doc = {");
var first = true;
foreach (var kv in doc) {
    if (!first) {
        jsonDoc.Append(",");
    }
    first = false;

    jsonDoc.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}", kv.Key, kv.Value);
}
jsonDoc.Append("};");

var je = new JintEngine();
je.Run(jsonDoc.ToString());

var result = je.Run(command);
return result;
```

Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could utilize `dynamic` to allow the dot notation syntax into the dictionary. I haven't tested with JINT, but I think it would work.

Here is an example of wrapping a Dictionary based on `DynamicObject` (some type safety ignored, but you get the general idea :-)). You should be able to adapt this to work with JINT.

```
void Main()
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string,object> { 
        { "x", 5 }, { "Foo", "Bar" }
    };

    dynamic expando = new ExpandoDictionary(values);

    // We can lookup members in the dictionary by using dot notation on the dynamic expando
    Console.WriteLine(expando.x);
    // And assign new "members"
    expando.y = 42;
    expando.Bar = DateTime.Now;
    // The value set is in the dictionary
    Console.WriteLine(values["Bar"]);
}

public class ExpandoDictionary : DynamicObject 
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string,object> inner;

    public ExpandoDictionary(Dictionary<string,object> inner)
    {
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value) 
    {
        inner[binder.Name] = value;
        return true;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object value) 
    {
        return inner.TryGetValue(binder.Name, out value);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a great idea ... can a `dynamic` do custom lookups (via `Dictionary`) this way?  I thought `dynamic` used reflection to evaluate properties and methods, and obviously `Dictionary` keys are not properties.

Comment: @Scott, not directly, although an `ExpandoObject` comes very close. I will try to whip up an example of wrapping a Dictionary in a `dynamic`.

Comment: Also, this doesn't affect the validity of your answer, but I failed to mention that I'm working with .NET 3.5 here.  If you know of a non-dynamic solution, feel free to add another answer!

Comment: If you need it to work with .NET 3.5, using the JSON serialization approach might not be a bad idea. I can't think of anything better at the moment.

Comment: OK, I did some testing.  JINT treats `dynamic` the same as any other object, so it definitely doesn't work.  :(  
Now I'm wondering/hoping that JINT might have some extensible `JavaScriptObject` that had `TrySetMember` and `TryGetMember` methods -- that would be perfect!